# Ubuntu login screen doesn't show up after installing postgresql

Tags: ubuntu, graphics, postgresql, login-screen

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my new machine and everything works fine. However, when I install postgresql and shut down the computer, when I log back in, there's no graphical login screen. The screen flashes a login prompt (white text on a black screen), then flashes again and just displays a blinking white cursor in the top left of an otherwise totally black screen. At this point, I can type in my password and it lets me into a fully functional graphical ubuntu (although there do seem to be some graphical issues with Chrome)

If I uninstall postgresql, this problem goes away. But I need postgresql for work... so how can I have both a working login screen and a postgresql install?

UPDATE:
Through some more experimenting, I'm thinking that there's some collision between the graphics server and the postgresql server?  I found that by disabling the postgresql server at startup I can eliminate the issue.  I just run:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f postgresql remove
```

However, this obviously prevents posgresql from starting up when I log in... so if I want postgresql to be running when I log in... what do I do?

Comment: What a weird problem. It must be that the login manager is trying to access a misconfigured postgresql server, but I'm only guessing. Try to figure out if there is a connection between the two and steps needed to configure them properly. It's probably wort mentioning which login manager you are using.

Comment: I believe I'm using lightdm (whatever ships with stock ubuntu).  I have no idea what the connection between the two could be... trying to avoid diving into the source!)